# Work Item owner changes when changing status?

Tags: azure-devops

We are using the vsts on visualstudio.com, and the agile process. When I change an item from active to completed, it changes the owner from me to someone else.
Why is this? Is it because someone else should do the acceptance? When I register time to the task, all that time looks like it's done by the other person.
It feels weird that I loose my task this way.

Comment: Don't use work item tracking for individual time tracking. It's not intended for that.

Comment: @DanielMann Ok, disregard the time; why does it change owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the owner (assign to) won’t be changed when change active state to the other.

First, if the project uses Inherited process, you can check whether it has the related rule:

1. Go to admin page and select Process tab (https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_admin/_process)
2. Click the related Inherited process
3. Click the related Work item type
4. Select Rules tab and check all rules

Secondly, check whether there is the work item extension doing it, you can disable the extensions and check whether the issue persist.

Update:

That is by designed, for Agile and CMMI, you first resolve the bug, indicating that the bug has been fixed. Typically, the person who created the bug then verifies the fix and updates the State from Resolved to Closed. If more work has been found after a bug has been resolved or closed, it can be reactivated by setting the State to Committed or Active.

More information, you can check this feedback: [Bug - Assigned To Creator when Resolved](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/134377/bug-assigned-to-creator-when-resolved.html)

Comment: We are using the **Agile (default)** process. Opening the Agile process, looking at bug and task, I see no rules nor extensions. Everything is default and grayed out.

Comment: @CarlR Try to disable the possible extensions and check whether the issue still persist. On the other hand, does complete means close state?

Comment: We have no extensions installed. It occurs for example when going from Active to Resolved.

Comment: @CarlR Does other project with Agile process have the same issue? Does it change the state before save (once change Active to Resolved)? What's the detail history of that work item?

Comment: This is the only project we are using right now. It changes before save. So if I drag the item from active to resolved, it has a new owner. If I open the item and change the state, i see that the owner is changed and I can change it back to me before saving.

Comment: No history related to state changing?

Comment: Detail history of an item is:
1. Person A created the Bug
2. Person A changed the Priority to 1
3. Person A changed Assigned to Person A
4. Person B changed state from New to Active, made other changes (This includes Assigned to Person B)
5. Person B changed state from Actve to Resolved, made other changes (This includes Assigned to Person A)
6. Person B changed Assigned to Person B

(Sorry for potato formatting.)

Comment: @CarlR This is by designed, check the update of my answer.

Comment: This is very annoying, but thank you very much for the solution.